# SaaS for testing across mobile devices with Windows 10 support

Tags: software-development, software-testing, saas

I am looking for some sort of SaaS like Xamarin Test Cloud or SauceLabs but that supports Windows 10 devices as well as iOS and Android.

Does any such service exist?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that [BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com) fits all your needs. Not free, but I've tried them in the past and I'm glad to see they are still on track and offering a really brilliant service.